# CORS problem with Vue3/Axios login into Flask backend

Tags: vue.js, flask, axios, vuejs3, flask-cors

I am trying to implement login system using **Vue3/Axios**.

For the backend I use Flask with **CORS** configured.

```
crs.init_app(app, supports_credentials=True, origins=["http://127.0.0.1:3000"], resources={r"/api/v1/*"}, allow_headers=["*"], expose_headers=["*"])
```

At frontend side (vue 3), I am using axios with following configuration:
**axios.ts**

```
import axios from "axios";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:5000";
```

Inside Vue 3 login components, I have script section with respective variables and method which is called when login button is clicked.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
const router = useRouter();

const myForm = ref({
  username: "",
  password: "",
});

const handleLogin = async () => {
  await axios.post("/api/v1/account/token", {
    // await axios.post("/api/auth/user/100", {
    username: myForm.value.username,
    password: myForm.value.password,
  });
};
</script>
```

and linking variables defined in scripts section with the html input in the template section.

```
<template>
..........
<input
        type="text"
        v-model="myForm.username"
        id="username"
.............
<input
        type="password"
        v-model="myForm.password"
..........
</template>
```

When I fill the input forms with username/password and click on login button, request is received on flask backend:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jan/2023 15:55:37] "OPTIONS /api/v1/account/token HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jan/2023 15:55:37] "POST /api/v1/account/token HTTP/1.1" 401 -
```

and at the frontend side browser pop ups the new Sign In form.

[image]

If cancel is clicked browser inspection tool shows :

[image]

Otherwise, if correct username and password is provided on popped up login form then login is successful.
Full headers from browser inspection:
[image]
Kindly, advise what CORS configuration or procedure am I missing and how can I fix this , in order to login directly from HTML input forms without popping up additional logging form.

Comment: You have properly set your CORS here no? Your login is properly working too apparently, you need to provide some feedback to your frontend when the operation is successful (not sure about why you need/have that popup). If you press "Cancel", you're not authenticated and got a 401, which seems totally fine to me because you're canceling the authentication, the browser is then getting an answer of "I don't have access to the data since I'm not authorized" hence the 401 error.

Comment: When I input username/password and click login, Flask shows the following debug messages: 127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jan/2023 15:55:37] "OPTIONS /api/v1/account/token HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jan/2023 15:55:37] "POST /api/v1/account/token HTTP/1.1" 401 -. additional login form is popped up only after first login doesn't complete.

Comment: Since it's sending an `OPTIONS`, something is maybe wrong on the CORS side. I'm not a Flask expert so I couldn't say. Try with Postman to be sure if it it's a CORS issue. Send the same payload, if it works perfectly it means that it's CORS. If you have the same error, then it's maybe something else.

Comment: using postman everything works fine

Comment: Then, it's a CORS issue. Google on how to setup that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the way username and password is handled. For basic authentication in axios i have fixed :

```
const handleLogin = async () => {
  await axios.post(
    "/api/v1/account/token",
    {},
    {
      auth: {
        username: myForm.value.username,
        password: myForm.value.password,
      },
    }
  );
  router.push("/");
};
```